# How to effectively protect a VIP in the streets?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

A diplomat of a foreign country resides in the current city. Now he wants to go from the townhall to some event a couple of blocks down the street. How would you protect him, in case a group of highly skilled rogues and sorcerers wanted to kill him on the way?

I was thinking of a steel-plated carriage and a couple of city guards around it. The people in the city should not really be restricted in ways of locking down the street, in fact, they should not even register that inside this carriage is a "very important person".

What I'm afraid of is, if one of the sorcerers/wizards/whatever fires a scorching ray, a fireball or some similar magic weapon. So my main question is: Could someone who has to protect the VIP cast something like "[dispel greater magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic)" on the carriage even when moving, and does this protect the diplomat? What suggestions do you have?

BTW: Teleporting the diplomat would be "too magical" for the setting I am thinking of. **The magic level should not be higher than what a level 7 sorcerer/wizard is capable of.**

Comment: If *teleport* is too magical, so's [*telekinetic sphere*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telekinetic-sphere), right?

Comment: This "too magical" thing could use some additional explanation. There are lots of magical shortcuts that could be applied here.

Comment: What sort of maximum level of effects are you looking at, spell wise?

Comment: What race, what level and what class is the diplomat? If these aren't fixed / revealed yet for sure, consider giving a twist to the story, and have the diplomat be a "monster". ;) Allow the attackers to do away with the shabby protection measures the local guard has devised, and then reveal, upon him getting "wounded" first that the diplomat is a werewolf or something (a fact that perhaps even he's unaware of, and which fact raises further questions & complications: what do you do with a diplomat who turns out to be a monster? :)) (Should I turn this into an answer, or is it too out of scope?)

Comment: @OpaCitiZen: The idea is intriguing, but for my scenario not really fitting. Btw: the diplomat is a human aristocrat 9. But not that this really matters.

Comment: If it weren't for the role playing the best protection would be just wearing commoner clothes and staying inside the crowd...

Comment: Is teleport too magical even for the attackers? If the atttackers can use every trick in the bag it's almost impossible to protect someone who can't protect himself in a 3.PF game. If they are limited, maybe there are solutions, but they depend on the limits.

Comment: A highly skilled sorcerer would simply summon an _invisible stalker_. The stalker will almost certainly kill the diplomat. It will pursue the mark until the task has been fulfilled. It cannot be seen easily, even with magic, cannot be held back easily (the diplomat needs air to breathe!), protection from evil won't keep it at bay. It doesn't sleep nor eat nor rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a localized [anti-magic](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/antimagicField.html) field in the carriage.

This should take care of most casting, and give enough time to react in case of a "caster attack".

Also, put up a [Contingency](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/contingency.html) Spell with a Teleport to a safe location in the case of an attack. If "Teleport" don't suit's you well, you can put other spells to protect him, like a Dispel Magic, to trigger in case of need.

The noble can use a [Hat of Disguise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/hat-of-disguise) to escape detection, too.

Also, something that gives him Spell Resistance can be helpfull.

Comment: What is "RM"? Could you explain please?

Comment: One of the main problem an anti-magic field will cause is that the Contingency spell didn't work anymore and potential healer can't work in case of an assault right in the anti-magic field.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I used the Portuguese jargon. It was supposed to be "SR", or Spell Resistence. I will edit.

Comment: I'm a Brazillian player. Sometimes I mix up the english terms with the portuguese terms, and the result is something like that. RM is "Resistência a Magia", that is the Portuguese term for "Spell Resistence". Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Their are several strategies you can try but be aware, their is no perfect solution for this problem other than instant transport (may [Dimension Door](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door) is an option?). Even in this case the assassins could simply wait right at the spot.

**The Sneaky Ones**

Have a group of guards and a carriage going to the target. Be sure that no one can see who is in but spread the rumor before. Make him and yourself invisible with the [spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility) or a potion and walk to the location of the route the others take. You also could use some disguise mechanisms like of the item [Hat of Disguise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/hat-of-disguise).

Even if this didn't sounds very "orthodox" but you can also put him into an outer dimensional space and carry him their. Be aware that he needs some fresh air so provide him with an item which creates it or plan several breaks.

**The Confrontation Strategy**

If you like confrontation and don't want to trick the "assassins" it becomes complicated. Use spells to protect your target. Like:

- [Mage Armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-armor) which provides some AC.
- Take the damage yourself with spells like [Shield Other](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shield-other)
- Use [(lesser) Globe of Invulnerability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/globe-of-invulnerability) to protect him for most basic spells.
- Another fine spell would be the [Stone Skin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/stoneskin) spell which provides some DR.

Furthermore try to hide him to ensure that spells which work on sight couldn't kill him. Provide him with some potions that he could heal himself if he is wounded. Use some highly skilled scouts to ensure a safe path and to have the possibility for quick reactions. Do not show your whole crew right at the start, the enemy might find a way to get ride of all at once.

**Conclusion**

It is very hard to ensure a save trip for a diplomat or ambassador. Have a big variety of guys with you and expect the unexpected, you need to be able to adapt to the situation very quickly what ever will come and tries to kill your protege.

Comment: I second the sneaky options.

Answer (score 4):

I think I might cast [Greater Invisibility](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/invisibility.html#_invisibility-greater) on the diplomat.

Then I would Cast [Haste](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/haste.html#_haste) and [Fly](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/fly.html) on the diplomat.

I would also cast [Non-Detection](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/nondetection.html#_nondetection) as a precaution.

I would give him a scroll of [Dimension Door](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/dimensionDoor.html#_dimension-door) as a "Oh Crap" escape tool.

Then, instruct him to fly up 60 or 100 feet, and fly to the event. Maybe even while I do a fake carriage with guards and such as a distraction, so people wont even think to look for an invisible flying diplomat.