# Does Rope Trick move relatively?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Whilst thinking about [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/42093/how-to-effectively-protect-a-vip-in-the-streets) I wondered if [rope trick](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/ropeTrick.html) space is tied to where it is located in relative physical space for the plane it's on (after all, quite possibly if it's on a planet it's moving anyway with rotation...) OR if it's is tied to the object it is cast on (the rope) and it's relative position in magic-time-space.

The idea being; I have a carriage, I cast **rope trick** (with a 5ft piece of rope inside a 6ft high carriage) inside it. I have my VIP climb up inside the extra-dimensional space and drive the carriage to the location.

**Does the rope trick move with the carriage or is it tied to the planar location it's at initially?**

Comment: "Relatively" would imply "relative to some object;" "relativistically" would imply "near enough the speed of light that the effects of relativity should be considered."

Comment: Although, if the latter were in your D&D game…

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By EXACTLY the rules, it is undefined.

However, let's take into account the ***Skull & Shackles Player's Guide***. It says that the entrance created by this spell, if created on a ship, won't move along with the ship. You can check this [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/rope-trick), on the description of Rope Trick (Look at the lateral box, with the "by the way" clause).

It's trivial to suppose that if this spell don't move with a ship, it won't move with a carriage either!

Comment: My question with this knowledge would be, what happens if you DO cast it inside a carriage..and then move the carriage..? :)

Comment: @MikeRose either the carriage will fail to move because it will not be able to exert the 16000 pounds required to break the rope from the entrance, or the rope will come free from the entrance.

Comment: And if the rope was pulled in, the VIP will have a nasty surprise...

Comment: @G0BLiN Unfortunatelly, you can't pull the rope in anymore... pathfinder removed that trick from the rules.

Comment: @ColinD: hey, never mind disappearing into the hole, a 16000lb load-bearing rope attached to a skyhook is a pretty handy tool ;-)

Comment: Makes sense to me; and yeah, shame you can't pull the rope up inside anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with KRyan, that it will have to be undefined and left to the GM.

That being said, if we look at some "moveable" extradimensional spaces, we can argue that rope trick may have to be stationary.

If we look at portable hole...

> PORTABLE HOLE
>   Aura strong conjuration; CL 12th
>   Slot none; Price 20,000 gp; Weight —
>   DESCRIPTION
>   A portable hole is a circle of cloth spun from the webs of a phase spider interwoven with strands of ether and beams of starlight, resulting in a portable extradimensional space. When opened fully, a portable hole is 6 feet in diameter, but it can be folded up to be as small as a pocket handkerchief. When spread upon any surface, it causes an extradimensional space 10 feet deep to come into being. This hole can be picked up from inside or out by simply taking hold of the edges of the cloth and folding it up. Either way, the entrance disappears, but anything inside the hole remains, traveling with the item.
>
> The only air in the hole is that which enters when the hole is opened. It contains enough air to supply one Medium creature or two Small creatures for 10 minutes. The cloth does not accumulate weight even if its hole is filled. Each portable hole opens on its own particular nondimensional space. If a bag of holding is placed within a portable hole, a rift to the Astral Plane is torn in that place. Both the bag and the cloth are sucked into the void and forever lost. If a portable hole is placed within a bag of holding, it opens a gate to the Astral Plane. The hole, the bag, and any creatures within a 10-foot radius are drawn there, the portable hole and bag of holding being destroyed in the process.
>
> CONSTRUCTION
>   Requirements Craft Wondrous Item, **plane shift**; Cost 10,000 gp>

We see that it requires plane shift to create, which is a 5th level spell, opposed to the 2nd level rope trick is.

Also, we can look at Bag of Holding...

> BAG OF HOLDING
>   Aura moderate conjuration; CL 9th
>   Slot none; Price see below; Weight see below
>   DESCRIPTION
>   This appears to be a common cloth sack about 2 feet by 4 feet in size. The bag of holding opens into a nondimensional space: its inside is larger than its outside dimensions. Regardless of what is put into the bag, it weighs a fixed amount. This weight, and the limits in weight and volume of the bag's contents, depend on the bag's type, as shown on the table below.
>
> Bag    Bag Weight  Contents Limit  Contents Volume Limit   Market Price
>   Type I  15 lbs. 250 lbs.    30 cubic ft.    2,500 gp
>   Type II 25 lbs. 500 lbs.    70 cubic ft.    5,000 gp
>   Type III    35 lbs. 1,000 lbs.  150 cubic ft.   7,400 gp
>   Type IV 60 lbs. 1,500 lbs.  250 cubic ft.   10,000 gp
>   If a bag of holding is overloaded, or if sharp objects pierce it (from inside or outside), the bag immediately ruptures and is ruined, and all contents are lost forever. If a bag of holding is turned inside out, all of its contents spill out, unharmed, but the bag must be put right before it can be used again. If living creatures are placed within the bag, they can survive for up to 10 minutes, after which time they suffocate. Retrieving a specific item from a bag of holding is a move action, unless the bag contains more than an ordinary backpack would hold, in which case retrieving a specific item is a full-round action. Magic items placed inside the bag do not offer any benefit to the character carrying the bag.
>
> If a bag of holding is placed within a portable hole, a rift to the Astral Plane is torn in the space: bag and hole alike are sucked into the void and forever lost. If a portable hole is placed within a bag of holding, it opens a gate to the Astral Plane: the hole, the bag, and any creatures within a 10-foot radius are drawn there, destroying the portable hole and bag of holding in the process.
>
> CONSTRUCTION
>   Requirements Craft Wondrous Item, **secret chest**; Cost 1,250 gp (type I), 2,500 gp (type II), 3,700 gp (type III), 5,000 gp (type IV)

You see secret chest, which is also a 5th level spell needed to create.

Lastly, there is Handy Haversack...

> HANDY HAVERSACK
>   Aura moderate conjuration; CL 9th
>   Slot none; Price 2,000 gp; Weight 5 lbs.
>   DESCRIPTION
>   A backpack of this sort appears to be well made, well used, and quite ordinary. It is constructed of finely tanned leather, and the straps have brass hardware and buckles. It has two side pouches, each of which appears large enough to hold about a quart of material. In fact, each is like a bag of holding and can actually hold material of as much as 2 cubic feet in volume or 20 pounds in weight. The large central portion of the pack can contain up to 8 cubic feet or 80 pounds of material. Even when so filled, the backpack always weighs only 5 pounds.
>
> While such storage is useful enough, the pack has an even greater power. When the wearer reaches into it for a specific item, that item is always on top. Thus, no digging around and fumbling is ever necessary to find what a haversack contains. Retrieving any specific item from a haversack is a move action, but it does not provoke the attacks of opportunity that retrieving a stored item usually does.
>
> CONSTRUCTION
>   Requirements Craft Wondrous Item, secret chest; Cost 1,000 gp

Also taking a 5th level spell.

You can see all of those are actually much smaller than the space created by rope trick, (8 people of any size) and can be moved around, especially the portable hole, it is very small. Yet they all take much higher level spells than rope trick.

So from that, you could assume rope trick is stationary, but again its all conjecture.

Comment: Check my answer. It is defined, in a way, for Pathfinder.

Comment: Indeed it is, I must have been writing my answer when you answered yours :) I assumed it was stationary anyway, but couldnt find a source for it.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is relative. When you place a Rope Trick, or any effect, you're clearly putting it in your frame of reference. Imagine if the rope trick was rooted to your Sun's frame of reference instead. It would (from your point of view) very rapidly fly away from you (and from the rapidly moving planet you happen to be standing on.)

I've always had it fixed in place relative to the coordinates on the surface of the caster's planet. (So casting it in a boat or carriage is probably a mistake, especially if the rope if left hanging down for more than a few moments....) Silly? Sure, but it's magic. That approach will work until playeys start wondering what happens if they cast it on the Astral or Etheral or whatever Otherly places your game contains.

A worse question is, how firmly does the spell told the rope, if the rope is dragged? Imagine the rope trick is cast on the deck of a boat, and the boat sails out from under it - at least, until the rope gets tangled in the rigging. Does the rope get destroyed, does the spell fail, does the spell get dragged, does the boat get stopped...?

Have fun, I say. Just remember that whatever answer you give, you are giving your players a new tool to abuse in creative ways. Even "spell fails" is a dangerous answer ("Wait, my opponent vanished up into a rope trick? I grab the end and tie it to my horse! Giddyap, Silver, we got him now!")